# how to select record from MySQL if date is in '14-AUG-2012' format

Tags: mysql

I have one query I am using following query to select record from MySQL

```
mysql> select VID from tm_visitor where DATE(INTIME)=DATE('2012-08-01');
```

then I am getting result as

```
+--------+
| VID    |
+--------+
| 000001 |
| 000002 |
| 000003 |
| 000004 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I use query as

```
mysql> select VID from tm_visitor where DATE(INTIME)=DATE('01-AUG-2012');
```

it gives me nothing

```
Empty set, 8 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: try using date_format http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
select VID from tm_visitor where DATE(INTIME) = STR_TO_DATE('01-AUG-2012', '%d-%b-%y')
```

See [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for more examples

Comment: @ babooney: It worked,Thanks But it should be like select VID from tm_visitor where DATE(INTIME) = STR_TO_DATE('01-AUG-2012', '%d-%M-%Y')